# A symmetric matrix is diagonalized by a matrix of its orthonormal eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

A proof of this statement is given in appendix A of [this document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf).

However, the author proves that every symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors. After the proof, it reads:

> By the second part of the proof, we know that the eigenvectors of A
>   are all orthonormal (we choose the eigenvectors to be normalized).

Well, we know every symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors. But they are not always orthonormal! We can't (or can we) always choose orthonormal eigenvectors.

I guess it's that the statement is proved for a more general case (orthogonality) Then it works for orthonormal vectors as well.

Comment: If your question is can we choose orthonormal eigenvectors when we have orthogonal eigenvectors, then the answer is yes, since we can take any multiple (i.e. divide by its magnitude) of an eigenvector and have it still be an eigenvector

Comment: what do you mean that they are orthogonal but not orthonormal? just divide by their lengths to make them unit length.

Comment: I don't get it. For matrix $A$, there is a unique set of values $\lambda_i$ and non-zero vectors $x_i$ such that $Ax_i=\lambda_i x_i$. These pairs are called eigenvectors and eigenvalues. AFAIK, I start by finding eigenvalues. Then I find vectors $x_i$ satisfying the equation $Ax_i=\lambda_i x_i$. These vectors don't necessarily have unit length.